# How to change focus from one EditText field to the next EditText field programmatically?

Tags: android

I have the following layout in my Android app:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="org.myorganization.MyViewModel" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText01"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:text="\u00B0"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText02"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:text="'"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText03"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:text='\"'
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText04"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:text="\u00B0"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText05"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:text="'"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText06"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:text='\"'
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextExternal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLength="150" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Cancel" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Save" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

I want to be able to move from one EditText field to another programmatically (i.e., from within the Java code), but I cannot figure out how to do it. I have tried many variations of this:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(editText01,2,3,4,5,6);
editText.focusSearch(FOCUS_RIGHT, FOCUS_LEFT, FOCUS_UP, FOCUS_DOWN);

editText.setFocusable();
editText.getFocusable();

editText.setFocusable(editText.getNextFocusForwardId());
...
```

And even:

```
editText.focusSearch(FOCUS_FORWARD);
```

Which, for some reason, AndroidStudio will not let me do.

What I am trying to do is emulate a keyboard and replicating the "Next" button. I used the tutorial found **[HERE](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/creating-an-in-app-keyboard-for-your-android-apps-a0a6c6e1e289)**

So, how can I change focus from one EditText field to the next EditText field programmatically in Android?

---

**EDIT:**

Here is my code I used for the `EditText.requestFocus()` solution:

```
private View.OnFocusChangeListener fieldFocusListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean isFocused)
    {
        if (isFocused)
        {
            int nextField = 0;
            EditText[] editTexts = {findViewById(R.id.editText01), findViewById(R.id.editText02), findViewById(R.id.editText03), findViewById(R.id.editText04), findViewById(R.id.editText05), findViewById(R.id.editText06)};
            EditText editText = findViewById(view.getId());

            for (int i = 0; i < editTexts.length; i++)
            {
                if (editTexts[i] == editText)
                    binding.customKeybaordLayout.setFocusedField(editTexts[(i != (editTexts.length - 1)) ? (i + 1) : 0]);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `editText.requestFocus();` to go to the editText that you want,
and then open the keyboard using the code below:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

You can use the below code to open the keyboard forcefully:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

You have to set the `android:nextFocusDown` in your XML and set which `EditText` you want to be focused after this one.

After that, you need to get the Next Focusable EditText/View using the code below:

```
EditText nextEditText = (EditText)currentEditText.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
nextEditText.requestFocus();
```

Comment: I am assuming that I need to use `editText.requestFocus()` on the next EditText field. How do I get hold of the next field in order to do this?

Comment: Yes, you have to do that in the next EditText field. You can do that if you have statically added EditText's, you just need to go to the next EditText that you want whenever the button is clicked.

Comment: Is there a way to get the next field dynamically? I don't want to have to have a huge `if/else` or `switch` block in order to handle this.

Comment: Tell me if it worked for you, and which part worked so i can remove unnecessary stuff

Comment: The `EditText.requestFocus()` definitely worked. I ended up creating an array of the 6 pertinent EditText fields in my layout. I iterated over them until I found the one that matched the currently focused EditText. When I found the currently focused EditText, I added `1` to the array value and requested focus for that EditText field. If the array value equaled the array length, I just used `0` to put the user back to the beginning of the series of EditText fields. I'll post my code in my original post.

Comment: Okay so did you not use the stuff that I added later to find the next focusable edittext?

Comment: I did not. I implemented my solution before you posted your edits. Thank you for your initial assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You must use editText.requestFocus();

Comment: I am assuming that I need to use `editText.requestFocus()` on the next EditText field. How do I get hold of the next field in order to do this?

Comment: then you set nextFocusUp, nextFocusDown or whatever nextFocus you need in your view on your xml file, then you can write editText.getNexFocusUpId() to check the id of the next view